# Where to look which Pokémon are banned in rated matchmaking?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm currently building a team for competitive use. I want to use the ingame matchmaking of the Pokémon XY games (Battle Zone).

I know Pokémons can be banned for reasons, therefore I didn't build a legendary into my team. But in unranked games (never tried ranked before) I often see them. As it's unranked, I use this fact as an excuse, it's a fun mode. But are they actually banned in ranked?

I know there is a [Tier list for XY](http://www.smogon.com/xyhub/tiers) on Smogon, but I guess it doesn't cover the ingame matchmaking.

**Are there Pokémon banned in ranked matchmaking and if so, is there a list of Pokémons/items/abilities listed to look at?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to compete, you have to sync your game to [Pokemon Global Link](http://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/). From there, you should be able to access the news page where the regulations for the competitions will be displayed (you don't actually have to log in though, you just go to the page).

The rules and regulations for each rating battle season can vary, but for the current one (season 2), you have the [following rules](http://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/information/356321fc-2949-45bc-a3ce-b0f8279dc295) for legible Pokemon:

> Players may use Pokémon from the Central Kalos Pokédex from #001 to #150, Coastal Kalos Pokédex from #001 to #153, or Mountain Kalos Pokédex from #001 to #147.

Comment: Oh so it's only possible to use Pokémons of the Gen VI Pokédex? Interesting thing... :) Thanks for that!

Comment: @Trollwut interestingly, they only seem to have ever explicitly banned Kalos legendaries in any mode. Free Mode is now full of pokebank legendaries (many of which are stronger than many Kalos banned legendaries like the birds...)

Comment: Free mode, yes. But they aren't covered within ranked because of the Pokédexes, I guess.